# Rewrite Rule Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My URLs look like this

```
mydomain.tld/abc
de.mydomain.tld/abc
```

(optional there is a slash afterwards)

Now I want to rewrite all url with a subdomain, from:

```
de.mydomain.tld/abc (or de.mydomain.tld/abc/)
```

to:

```
de.mydomain.tld/abc.html
```

and all other urls should go to my ghost blog (line 5). This part works already.

**my .htaccess**

```
 1   RewriteEngine On
 2   #Rewrite my Subdomain to .html
 3   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.mydomain\.tld$ 
 4   RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1\.html [L] 

 5   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:61222/$1 [P]
 6   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

So far I thought it does this:

1 (line 3). If the url has the subdomain path within do the rule below.

2 (line 4) Rewrite the part before the slash (if there is one) to exactly the same with .html appended, use no more rules afterwards

**Question I:**
How to adjust lines 3,4 that only path which have the de. subdomain are changed to .html like described above the htaccess?

**Question II:**
Is the following part redirecting all www. subdomains to the original domain:
http://www.abc.de -> http://abc.de

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

If it is doing that do I need to move it upwards because I have the [L] in the first rule? If it is doing nothing, what would be the correct rewrite rule?

Comment: Sorry your question isn't clear. What problem are you facing and what do you mean by `www -> http://`

Comment: I edited it. I hope it is more clear now?

Comment: 1. Your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.mydomain\.tld$` is already doing this. 2. I don't see `www` removal in these rules. And don't understand why do you have `P` flag there.

Comment: Line 5 is fine. The P is for Proxy and I think it is because of ghost.
https://wiki.uberspace.de/cool:ghost?s[]=ghost it is in this tutorial

Comment: The first block is not working. 
I found this:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
So one error is already that I try to escape the . before html. correctly it has to be:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]
but is still not removing the slash, if there is one in the original url (e.g. http://abc.de/ --> http://abc.de/.html)
also the Rewrite Condition does not detect the subdomain, I think it maybe because it evaluates the part after the rootdomain?

Comment: `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/` is pretty much useless for rules testing. Better you test it locally on your web server.

Comment: Hmm this:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vardump
RewriteRule (.*) <a href="http://autofokus-marketing.de/$1?vardump&thereq=%{THE_REQUEST}&reqhost=%{HTTP_HOST}">http://autofokus-marketing.de/$1?vardump&thereq=%{THE_REQUEST}&reqhost=%{HTTP_HOST}</a> [R=301,L,QSA]
This kills my whole page.

The other option with
RewriteLog does not work on shared hosting

So is there a good debvug option, because otherwise I have to stick to the htaccess.madewithlove.be site?

But as mentioned the code doesn't work on my server. So it can't be valid.